# Going to next form through validation by checking textboxes and checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, validation, bootstrap-modal

I got a form with 2 textboxes and 1 checkbox. I'm having trouble validating the form. My goal is to check if the user checked the checkbox or wrote in the textboxes. If the user wrote inde both the textbox OR checked the checkbox then they could continue to the next form. If not then a dialogbox should appear. How do i accomplish this?

[image]

My Pseudo Code:

```
if (checkBox1.Checked)
{
    //Go to next Form
}
else
{
    if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox2.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill in the textboxes or mark the checkbox to continue");
    }
    else
    {
        //Go to next Form
    }
}
```

My HTML Form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>

    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function()
    {
        jQuery('#continue').on('click', function()
        {
            jQuery('#stepTwoForm').submit();
            return false;
        })

    })
    </script>


</head>

<body>
        <form id="stepTwoForm" action="NextForm.php" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Textbox1" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Textbox1</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <input name="Textbox1" type="text" class="form-control" id="Textbox1">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Textbox2" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Textbox2</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <input name="Textbox2" type="text" class="form-control" id="Textbox2">
                </div>
              </div>

          <center><input type="checkbox" name="checkboxName" id="checkboxID" value="Bike"> If checked go to next page or else fill out the textboxes</center>
        </form>

    <center><a id="continue" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" href="#">Continue</a></center>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use javascript or jquery to validate the form before you submit it.  If you check to see that the checkbox is checked or the inputs are populated then use either and `alert()` or display a hidden message to inform the user of the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok if you use the jquery to validate the form before submission then you can inform the user of the mistakes.  Have a look at the code below, this should get you going in the right direction, it will provide an alert to the user if the checkbox is not selected and the inputs are empty, otherwise it will submit the form.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $( '#continue' ).on( 'click', function()
    {
        if( $( '#checkboxID' ).is( ':checked' ) )
      {
        $( '#stepTwoForm' ).submit();
      }
      else
      {
        if( $( 'input[name=Textbox1]' ).val() == '' || $( 'input[name=Textbox2]' ).val() == '' )
        {
          alert( 'Please fill in the textboxes or mark the checkbox to continue' );
        }
        else
        {
          $( '#stepTwoForm' ).submit();
        }
      }
    })
  })
</script>
```

Working example - https://jsfiddle.net/Lhuaz0fn/